# How to determine Plasma Cleaning process completeness?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, plasma-physics

I'm trying to optimize plasma cleaning process to be signal driven instead of fixed time.
I have a vacuum chamber with hydrocarbon contaminants, I use air plasma for cleaning. Is there an option to terminate plasma, based on the amount of contaminants left in the chamber?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about physics, but a technique https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasma_cleaning

Comment: @annav is there any other site suitable for this question?

Comment: just found this by asking for "plasma cleaning process site " https://plasma-treating.com/about-plasma-plasma-cleaning.html

Comment: @annav I'm a semiconductor physicist, and plasma cleaning (and physical processes relevant in that technique) are one of my most important tools, on par with all the theories and models. Besides - page you provided is useless in the context of the question. Literally marketing for the beginners.

Comment: I just gave an example of searching. I looked at the sites of stack exchange and could not find in engineering an appropriate tag

Comment: maybe you could look https://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a nice research question, and as I see, some people studied very similar things, so here I can give you some references.

In "Process control of RF plasma assisted surface cleaning" H. Steffen and his colleagues write that:

> "An optical multichannel analyzer (OSMA, SI) was used for optical
> emission spectroscopy (OES) for a real-timediag- nostic of the
> discharge during the plasma process. A lot of spectral lines and bands
> can be obtained during the reactive removal of hydrocarbons by a
> plasma. They disappear after a certain time which is characteristic of
> the surface cleaning [ 10,15]. "

It isn't however that simple. You can monitor some spectroscopic bands to detect the cleaning endpoint BUT there is some catch of practical meaning:

> For the end point detection of CO it was found that the band heads
> completely disappear faster than the H,-line. However, this is not a
> solid proof for a totally cleaned surface. Sometimes if the lubricant
> film was very thick polymerization layers on the A1 surfaces have been
> observed. These polymers could not be removed by oxygen and not even
> by argon and hydrogen. In those cases no CO-bands could be observed at
> the plasma process. Nevertheless, a higher power input and increased
> cleaning time could remove those polymers, too.

I recommend reading the whole article, because it is not only clearly written, but also has other practical remarks you can use to get more ideas about your problem.